# The disabled edit text looks awkward; missing padding

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, design

Normally, the action links below the post have a `padding: 0px 3px 2px 3px;` applied to them, which gives them the spacing to the left and the right to "separate" them from the vertical bars. However, the new disabled edit text doesn't appear to get this padding, and looks a bit awkward so close to the two vertical bars.

[image: Edit link on Stack Overflow]

It's less noticeable on sites that don't have the vertical bars, but can still be seen by hovering over a link next to it.

[image: Edit link on Arqade]

Can the normal padding be applied to the disabled edit text?

Comment: Yay this is fixed!